# Snowflake Variant to pyspark array

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Hello I have a Array field in snowflake stored as `variant` and when I read it I get it back as String in pyspark. How can I convert the string into Array back so that I can apply explode over it?

Below is the VARIANT from snowflake:
[image]

In pyspark I tried splitting the field and casting it to array however when I explode the array the values are not the expected strings. It contains double quotes and even the square bracket. I wanted output without quotes and square brackets like a Pyspark array field would result in after explode operation.

```
df = df.withColumn("genres", split(col("genres"), ",").cast("array<string>"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the Data Type Mappings (from Snowflake to Spark), you see that the VARIANT datatype is mapped to StringType:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#from-snowflake-to-spark-sql

This is why you get those quotes and square brackets. I think the solution is to covert the variant to string explicitly using ARRAY_TO_STRING when querying the table, and then convert the string to array in Spark:

```
df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME) \
  .options(**sfOptions) \
  .option("query",  "select ARRAY_TO_STRING(genres,',') genres from test_v") \
  .load()

df = df.withColumn("genres", split(col("genres"), ",").cast("array<string>"))

df.show()
```

In my tests, it returns the following output:

```
+---------------+
|         genres|
+---------------+
|[News, Weather]|
+---------------+
```